# How to set empty activity as default activity and name it in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am learning how to make a android app, so I bought a book "Head First Android Development 2nd Edition", it uses Android Studio v2.3 while it is v3.3 in my computer.

When creating a new project and choose a empty activity, there are differences in two versions. In v2.3, after choosing a empty activity, you can enter Application name, Minimun SDK, which is the same as v3.3 .

v2.3 can also enter "Activity name" and "Layout name" so that Android Studio will automatically create an empty activity and a layout whose name accords with what you input in "Activity name" and "Layout name". However I can't do it in v3.3 , are there other settings that I should change in order to have the right configuration as I want or what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `AndroidManifest.xml` and Change Activity Tag as follows:

```
<activity android:name="EmptyActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to Refactor the activity name and change the Intent - filter in the Manifest to the activity you want to be the default one.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I am quite new to Android Studio, so it is possible for you to clarify a little bit more clear?

Comment: Sure, to change the name of the Activity, right click on the file name and there you will see an option - REFACTOR ( you can also find it in the menu on top of the studio.)

Secondly, to set an activity as a default activity, go to Manifest, there you will see these lines 

 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
 </intent-filter>

Cut and paste these under the activity you want to set as default.

Comment: Let me know, if you need more help :)

Comment: Sorry, is "Manifest" a file? If it is, which folder is it in? And how to set it not to use Backwards Compatibility(AppCompat)?

Comment: On the left side of Android Studio, you will see app, under which are folders like manifest, java, res.

Answer (score 0):

You can Refactor the activity name by Shift+f6 and then 
open AndroidManifest.xml file and Change it as follow:

```
<activity android:name=".view.UI.EmptyActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```